# Is a martingale conditioned to be large a submartingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $X$ be a continuous time martingale such that $X_\infty := \lim_{t \to \infty} X_t$ exists almost surely. Let $x \in \mathbb R$ be such that $\mathbb P(X_\infty \geq x) > 0$, and define the probability measure $\mathbb Q$ by

$$\mathbb Q(E) :=\frac{\mathbb P(\{X_\infty \geq x\} \cap E)}{\mathbb P(\{X_\infty \geq x\})}$$

for all events $E$.

**Question:** Is is true that $X$ is a submartingale under $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Perhaps a very naive comment: is it clear that $\mathbb Q$ is actually independent of $t$? otherwise the question does not really make sense, does it?

Comment: @leo monsaingeon Oh I’m sorry, it should read $X_\infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

For a simple counterexample, let's work in discrete time.  Consider the following gambling strategy: start with \$0 and bet \$1 on a fair coin flip. If you win, you take your dollar and go home.  If you lose, then bet \$100 on a second fair coin flip, and quit after that.

Think of $x = 50$.  In order to have a chance to finish with more than \$50, you must *lose* a dollar on the first flip.  So conditioned on finishing with more than \$50, the first round of the game is unfavorable - indeed a guaranteed loss.

Formally, we have
$$\begin{align*}
P(X_1 = X_2 = 1) &= 1/2 \\
P(X_1 = -1, X_2 = 99) &= 1/4 \\
P(X_1 = -1, X_2 = -101) &= 1/4
\end{align*}$$
but $Q(X_1 = -1, X_2 = 99) = 1$.

For a continuous time example, you could do something like the following: let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $\tau_y$ the hitting time of level $y$.  Take the stopping time $\tau$ defined by
$$\tau = \begin{cases} \tau_1, & \text{if } \tau_1 \le 1 \\
1, & \text{if } \tau_1 > 1 \text{ and } B_1 \ge -1 \\
\tau_{100}, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
Then if $X_t = B_{t \wedge \tau}$ and $x=50$, we have $Q(X_1 < -1) = 1$.

Comment: Very nice example. Conditioning on the end result is a pretty poorly behaved operation!